# Creating rdd from another rdd with required specific columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a file in spark with following table data

```
Property ID|Location|Price|Bedrooms|Bathrooms|Size|Price SQ Ft|Status
```

I have read this file as rdd using :-

```
a = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/realestate.txt")
```

Now I need to Create a new RDD having PropertyID, Location, Price (= size * Price SQ Ft) from the above RDD.

I am able to do it by converting it to dataframe but not able to figure out how to convert it to another RDD using with required columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first three columns using a map:

```
a = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/realestate.txt")
b = a.map(
    lambda x: 
    (x.split('|')[:2] + [float(x.split('|')[5]) * float(x.split('|')[6])]) 
    if x.split('|')[0] != 'Property ID'
    else ['Property ID', 'Location', 'Price']
)
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot. Can you explain why you have used this if else statement.

Comment: Because the header cannot be converted to float

Comment: Can you explain more when this if statement is working and when the else part.

Comment: the if statement is satisfied for every row except the header row. the else statement only applies for the header row

Comment: Thanks a lot @mck. Also if i am reading it as a dataframe like   df = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/tables/realestate.txt', header=True, inferSchema=True, sep='|').   New dataframe can be created as  ddf=df.select("Property ID","Location","Price").  How to set price = Size* Price SQ Ft.

Comment: just do `df2 = df.select('property id', 'location', (F.col('size')*F.col('price sq ft')).alias('price')`

Answer (score 0):

```
def splitfunc(x):
    array=x.split('|')
    return [array[0],array[1],array[5]*array[6]]
#array[0] is your properties and so on..
newrdd=rdd.map(splitfunc)
```

use a map function..In map function split the rdd on seperator(lines.split('|')), and then select necessary columns in array.